# Google login iOS error "Access Not Configured , activate the API for your project"

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-signin

I have integrated my iOS app with Google plus and I keep getting this error for the past few weeks. I did ensure that `Contacts API` and `Google+ API` are enabled on the developer console but I am still receiving this error.

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)" UserInfo=0xc8645c0 {error=Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project., GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0xc876bc0: {message:"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." code:403 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.)}

Comment: So this happened while using SDK version 1.3. Upgrading it to 1.5 made it work correctly.